# How to setup GStreamer Editing Services 1.2.0 (GES) environment on windows VS2012 or VS2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, plugins, gstreamer

I just downloaded gstreamer 1.2.4 both normal and developer packs from [here](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/1.2.4/), and performed full installs of both packs.

Then I added bin location to path variable, then created c++ solution and added `x86.props` and `gstreamer-1.0.props`. I wanted to check some basic GES project, but I'm unable to do it since not all dependencies are resolved. Visual studio 2012 shows:

```
cannot include file : 'ges/ges-version.h'. No such file or directory.
```

How can I setup GES working environment on Visual Studio? What props do I need to add to my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing gst-editing-services-1.0.props file was added in 1.2.4.1 version. You can download it from here http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/1.2.4.1/ .